# How to query for related rows based on a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a couple of DB tables named `order` and `order_items`

```
order
- id
- created_date
- type ('SALE', 'RETURN')

order_item
- id
- order_id
- type ('SALE', 'RETURN')
- original_order_id
- original_order_item_id
- subtotal
```

When the SALE happens a corresponding row is inserted into `order` and `order_item` tables with `type=SALE` and when a RETURN happens on that item, a new row is inserted in `order` and `order_item` with `type=RETURN` and `order_item.original_order_id` with SALE order id and  `order_item.original_order_item_id` with its corresponding SALE order item id.

I am trying to write a query, to fetch SALE transactions between a given date range and find their returns as well.

The below query gives me SALE transactions between specific dates

```
SELECT order.id, order_item.id, order_item.created_date, order_item.subtotal
FROM order as order, order_item as  order_item
WHERE
order.id=order_item.id AND
order.created_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-01-01 00:00:00' AND
order.type='SALE'
```

Do I need to make the above an inline query and join it with the `order_item` table comparing `original_order_id` and `original_order_item_id` or is there any better and more efficient way of getting SALE and their related RETURN records?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you don't need it, but as JOIN a the modern way, you also should use it

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you're looking for something like the following query

```
SELECT sale.id                    sale_id, 
       sale_item.id               sale_item_id, 
       sale_item.created_date     sale_item_date, 
       sale_item.subtotal         sale_item_subtotal,
       returned.id                returned_id,
       returned_item.id           returned_item_id,
       returned_item.created_date returned_item_date,
       returned_item.subtotal     returned_item_subtotal
  FROM order sale 
       INNER JOIN order_item sale_item ON sale.id = sale_item.order_id
       LEFT JOIN order_item returned_item ON sale_item.original_order_item_id = returned_item.id
       LEFT JOIN order returned ON returned.id = returned_item.order_id
WHERE sale.type = 'SALE'
  AND sale.created_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-01-01 00:00:00';
```

This is just a sketch and contains errors (e. g. `order` is a keyword and therefore not a valid table name, but since you used it in your example, I didn't change it).

Due to the LEFT JOIN, the result will contain all sale records and its corresponding sale_item records but missing returned_item and returned records will be filled with `NULL` values. In other words: for items which were not returned, the `returned_xxx` columns will be `NULL`.